# How to access img src in div tags

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery

I am just wondering how I can access the img src (ID wows1_0) that is located within two div tags and then be able to change the src via javascript.

```
<div id="wowslider-container1" class="grid_7 alignGallery">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
        <li><img src="WOWSlider/data1/images/BookARoom.jpg" alt="full screen slider" title="full screen slider" id="wows1_0"/></li>
        <li><img src="WOWSlider/data1/images/ContactSupport.jpg" alt="ContactSupport" title="ContactSupport" id="wows1_1"/></li>
    </ul></div>
<div class="ws_thumbs">
    <div>
        <a href="#wows1_0" title="full screen slider"><img src="WOWSlider/data1/tooltips/bookaroom.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#wows1_1" title="ContactSupport"><img src="WOWSlider/data1/tooltips/contactsupport.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>               
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the `div` markup relevant to the issue? If you have an`img` element as the only child of an `a` element that has an `id` attribute, it is rather simple to access the `img` element. But is there some complication to this?

Comment: Hi Jukka,i am using wowslider these div's are used for the styling of the gallery

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, then:

```
$(".ws_images img").each(function() {
     console.log($(this).attr("src"));
     $(this).attr("src", value); // to set it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do by using pure javascript code. We can access it by using id of img with getElementById method and change the src using src property.

```
var image=document.getElementById("wows1_0");
image.src="ss.jpg";
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9rb3ahs3/1/

[image]

Comment: add the javascript code after page load, or after body tag

Comment: I have just inspected the element after the page loads and it is changing the src of the image but it is not updating it on the page weird, any suggestions?

Comment: I tried changing thumbnail instead of the main image that worked fine but for some reason the main image isn't updating when i change it?? http://prntscr.com/5yhesk

Answer (score 0):

If you  have an `img` element as the only child of an `a` element that has an `id` attribute, as it seems, you can access it rather simply, e.g.

```
document.getElementById("wows1_0").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src
```